# Should change the values if zero is present while moving to other viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to enter a phone number in UITextfield when I press the nextButton,that number should appear in the next view controller in UILabel .But the problem is if I enter a number starting with 00(two zeros) in the textfield it should change to ++ in the next viewcontroller. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: You are working on swift or obj C? A basic string manipulation can do this trick for you.

Comment: working on objective c

Comment: Yep added my answer on that :)

Comment: Great happy to help. Please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
if([oldString hasPrefix:@"00"]) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,2);
        NSString *newText = [oldString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"++"];
}
```

Comment: I think this will replace all the occurences of 00 with ++, say if user enters 00544003

Answer (score 1):

This will replace the occurence of 00 in the beginning with ++

For **Swift**

```
let str = "00044400"
if str.hasPrefix("00") {
    let i = 2
    let range = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)..<str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i)

    print(str.replacingCharacters(in: range, with:"++"))
}
```

For **Objective-C**

```
NSString *str = @"00044004";
NSString *newString = @"";
if ([str hasPrefix:@"00"]) {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 2);
    newString = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"++"];
    NSLog(@"NewString = %@", newString);

}
```